# dotnet quit unexpectedly - after creating new project in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm getting this warning while creating new MVC project using ASP.NET Core (both 3.1 version and 5.0 version):

> dotnet quit unexpectedly

Because the warning description does show me where the problem comes from, so I don't know where to start.

This is my `Startup.cs` file:

```cs
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        });
    }
}
```

> [image]

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple cases to get this warning. Some problem can be fixed inside the method `ConfigureServices` in the file `Startup.cs`.

If you are using Visual Studio, you can open `Application Output` tab *(View -> Other Windows -> Application Output)*.

If you've got some message, such as:

### Case 1:

> Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to find
> the required services. Please add all the required services by calling
> 'IServiceCollection.AddAuthorization' inside the call to
> 'ConfigureServices(...)' in the application startup code.

**Fixed:** Calling `services.AddAuthorization();` method inside the `ConfigureServices` method.

*Note:* It's **different** from `services.AddAuthentication();` *(this service can be used when you want to enable some services like: Login with Facebook/Google/Twitter...)*.

---

### Case 2:

> Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to find
> the required services. Please add all the required services by calling
> 'IServiceCollection.AddControllers' inside the call to
> 'ConfigureServices(...)' in the application startup code.

**Fixed:** Calling `services.AddControllersWithViews();` or `services.AddControllers();` service inside that method to solve the problem.

---

### Case 3:

> Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to find
> the required services. Please add all the required services by calling
> 'IServiceCollection.AddRazorPages' inside the call to
> 'ConfigureServices(...)' in the application startup code.

This error ocurrs when you enable to use [Razor Pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio). To solve this problem, you need to add `services.AddRazorPages();` service.

---

### Case 4:

> An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
>
> System.InvalidOperationException: No service for type
> 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]'
> has been registered.

You've got this error when missing to add identity service. This can be done by one of these ways:

```cs
services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options =>
{
    //options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
    //options.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
    //options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
    //options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
    //options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
}).AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

or

```cs
services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
{
    //options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
    //options.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
    //options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
    //options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
    //options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
}).AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

If you want to extend `IdentityUser` class to add more property like `LastSignedIn`:

```cs
public class User : IdentityUser
{
    public DateTimeOffset LastSignedIn { get; set; }
}
```

you can replace `IdentityUser` with `User` when adding identity service:

```cs
services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>(options => {})
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

---

### Case 5:

> Unhandled exception. System.AggregateException: Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser] Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserClaimsPrincipalFactory`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]': Unable to resolve service for type 'X.Data.ApplicationDbContext' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserOnlyStore`6[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser,X.Data.ApplicationDbContext,System.String,Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserClaim`1[System.String],Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserLogin`1[System.String],Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserToken`1[System.String]]'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser] Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]': Unable to resolve service for type 'X.Data.ApplicationDbContext' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserOnlyStore`6[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser,X.Data.ApplicationDbContext,System.String,Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserClaim`1[System.String],Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserLogin`1[System.String],Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserToken`1[System.String]]'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.ISecurityStampValidator Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SecurityStampValidator`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]': Unable to resolve service for type 'X.Data.ApplicationDbContext' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserOnlyStore`6[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser,X.Data.ApplicationDbContext,System.String,Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserClaim`1[System.String],Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserLogin`1[System.String],Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserToken`1[System.String]]'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.ITwoFactorSecurityStampValidator Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.TwoFactorSecurityStampValidator`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]': Unable to resolve service for type 'X.Data.ApplicationDbContext' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserOnlyStore`6[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser,X.Data.ApplicationDbContext,System.String,Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserClaim`1[System.String],Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserLogin`1[System.String],Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserToken`1[System.String]]'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser] Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]': Unable to resolve service for type 'X.Data.ApplicationDbContext' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserOnlyStore`6[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser,X.Data.ApplicationDbContext,System.String,Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserClaim`1[System.String],Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserLogin`1[System.String],Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserToken`1[System.String]]'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserStore`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser] Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserOnlyStore`6[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser,X.Data.ApplicationDbContext,System.String,Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserClaim`1[System.String],Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserLogin`1[System.String],Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserToken`1[System.String]]': Unable to resolve service for type 'X.Data.ApplicationDbContext' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserOnlyStore`6[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser,X.Data.ApplicationDbContext,System.String,Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserClaim`1[System.String],Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserLogin`1[System.String],Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserToken`1[System.String]]'.)

This error ocurrs when you forget to enabling `DbContext` service:

```cs
// in this example, we use "Sqlite" to manage connection
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlite(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

If you want to use SQL Server instead of Sqlite, you can add [Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer/) NPM package:

```cs
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
              options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

If you define `ApplicationDbContext` class in the class library project *(Namespace: Your_main_project_namespace.Data)*, when you refer it to the main project, you need to call `MigrationsAssembly` method with the namspace name of the main project:

```cs
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
              options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
              actions => actions.MigrationsAssembly("Your_main_project_namespace")));
```

*Note:* The current version (5.0.0) of this package is applied to [net5.0](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/5.0), so if you're using [netcoreapp3.1](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.1), you can use version 3.1.10 instead. Don't try to upgrade to the lastest, it will crash your project. Such as: removing/replacing some obsolete method/class/interface... *(`IWebHostEnvironment` vs `IHostingEnvironment`...)*.

---

### Case 6:

> Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'connectionString')

This error may come from your connection string name in the file `appsettings.json`:

```json
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "MyConnection": "DataSource=app.db;Cache=Shared"
  }
}
```

In this example, we name the connection string with the name `MyConnection`, so when we try to get:

```
Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")
```

the exception will be thrown because there is no property name `DefaultConnection`.

---

### Case 7:

This problem may come from the way to append a large of data files to project via copy-paste method using Finder (on Mac) or Explorer (on Windows). The general case is: Coping to `wwwroot` folder:

> [image: 1]

When Visual Studio is opening and some files are copied to `wwwroot` folder (or somewhere else in the project) successful, the project will be saved automatically. There is no way to stop it.

And the remaining time will be calculated based on:

- File count,
- file size,
- file type,
- the target folder *(wwwroot, node_modules...)*,
- and your hardware (CPU, RAM, HDD or SSD).

So, be careful if you want to copy more than 5000 images or videos to `wwwroot` folder. If something goes wrong *(I don't even know where the error comes from)*, you cannot run the project. In this case, I suggest:

- Wait until your project completes saving/loading/restoring. **DO NOT** take any action to try to stop or prevent it.
- Right click the project and choose `Edit Project File` to edit `.csproj` file. In this file, if you catch some implementation like this:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="wwwroot\">
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Always</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

The tag `<ItemGroup>` which contains `<Content>` tag, and the `<Content>` tag mentions about `wwwroot` folder or some folder name that inherits from `wwwroot` folder. **DELETE** all of them (including the parent tag: `<ItemGroup>`), save the file and wait until the file is saved/all packages are restored.

- Clean the project and buid/rebuild again.
- More action: If the building/loading speed of your project becomes very slow, try to right click on the target folder *(in this case: wwwroot)* and choose `Exclude From Project`. Then waiting until Visual Studio completes the action, and right click the folder to choose `Include From Project` again. Waiting action is required (the time to exclude/include may the same).